# How to wrap text in toc?

Tags: table-of-contents

I have long titles for my document chapter. These titles are going beyond the right margin.

How to word wrap section and subsection headings in toc?

Comment: Please provide a full working example including your documentclass and a sample heading

Comment: For the case that you are using »[hyperref](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)« you need to add the `breaklinks` option.

Comment: It is better you use the optional argument of the section etc to avoid cluttering toc.

Answer (score 0):

You could want to change the layout of the TOC page (only) in order to avoid titles split.

The geometrey package allows you to modify temporary  a page margins with these commands (I just put left and right margins because it relevant for your issue but there is also top and down margin options):

```
\newgeometry{lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\restoregeometry
```

You should be also aware that there is a way to define short versions of titles for the TOC. In this case, long versions are printed in the body of the document but the TOC shows shorter ones.

```
\chapter[Short title]{My very very very long title useless which does not fit in my toc page}
```

Comment: Given that most documents require fixed margins, it's really unlikely that this is a practical solution.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes it is not very nice but it does the job (if you are ok to lower your typography standard).